# What is the shape/order of cudnn convolutional filters?

Tags: cudnn

Cudnn stores its filters in an array. I know the total size of the array must be `num_filters_out * num_filters_in * height_filter * width_filter`. But how is the array ordered, actually?

Is it `(num_filters_out, num_filters_in, height_filter, width_filter)`, or is it a different permutation? (I guessed that one based on the signature of `cudnnSetFilter4dDescriptor`)

Answer (score 1):

It's usually as you said: "KCHW", i.e. (num_filters_out, num_filters_in, height_filter, width_filter).